# Django Error ''WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'Players''

Tags: django

I am trying to create a detailed page for each `player` from the `Players` model, but for some reason, I am getting this error. How can I fix this?

My models.py:

```
class Players(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    image_url = models.CharField(max_length=2083)
```

My views.py:

```
def PlayerDetailView(request, player):
    model = Players
    player = request.Players
    context = {'player' : player}
    return render(request, 'player_detail.html',  context)
```

My player_detail.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

    {% block content %}
        <h1>{{ player.name }}</h1>
        <img class="card-img-top" width="20" height="300" src="{{ player.image_url }}">
    {% endblock %}
```

My urls.py:

```
path('players/<str:player>', views.PlayerDetailView, name='player-detail'),
```

Comment: What is `player = request.Players` supposed to do?

Comment: sorry I forgot to give my urls.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the `Player` object with as name the `<str:player>` URL parameter with:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def PlayerDetailView(request, player):
    player = get_object_or_404(Players, name=player)
    context = {'player' : player}
    return render(request, 'player_detail.html',  context)
```

Typically however a *slug* is used, not the name of the `Player`, since that can result in "ugly" URLs if we work with spaces, accents, etc. For more information, see the [documentation on a `SlugField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#slugfield).

Comment: yea 6 more mins

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try

```
def PlayerDetailView(request, player):
    model = Players
    player = Players.objects.get(name=player)
    context = {'player' : player}
    return render(request, 'player_detail.html',  context)
```